# PyQt doesn't work with multiprocess (SEGFAULT) after packaging

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, multiprocessing, pyinstaller

I am currently trying to pack a script. it works perfectly when I run with python3 , but after I packing with py2app when using using multiprocessing. It shows process has segment fault.

If i put it into master process, it works for both before and after packaging.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing,logging



def Browse():
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


    import sys



    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    print('I can see this msg')


logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
logger.setLevel(multiprocessing.SUBDEBUG)
p = Process(target= Browse)
p.start()
p.join()
```

here is what i got

```
[INFO/Process-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `multiprocessing.set_executable()`, as [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_executable).